# How can I extend my displays and make my other monitor the main display with a shell script in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shell, script

Every time i plug in my monitor I need to manually extend the displays and switch the main monitor. I'd like to automate this with a shell script. The display arrangement is the same every time. I have no experience with writing shell scripts.

Comment: Having a script to run is no more efficient than pressing `Win` + `P`. Also, we're not a script writing service. You need to have a go first, then report your findings and where you're stuck. Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Writing the script is up to you, but
you can have a look at the NirSoft free tool of
[MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html):

> MultiMonitorTool is a small tool that allows you to do some actions related to working with multiple monitors. With MultiMonitorTool, you can disable/enable monitors, set the primary monitor, **save and load the configuration of all monitors**, and move windows from one monitor to another. You can do these actions from the user interface or from command-line, without displaying user interface. MultiMonitorTool also provides a preview window, which allows you to watch a preview of every monitor on your system.