# Extend to Display and switch to this Display as Main Display via .bat File or similar

Tags: display, batch-file, switch

I am using two monitors that are constantly active, a third one is only occasionally active. When i use it, i have to extend to this display (its labeled Monitor 2 then) and make it my main display.

Is there a batch command or similar to do this? Also a command to disable Display 2 and make Display 3 my main display again?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/1717504/how-can-i-extend-my-displays-and-make-my-other-monitor-the-main-display-with-a-s